# How to populate excel with VBA from nested JSON?

Tags: json, excel, vba, dictionary, nested

[JSON response](https://api.upsales.com/#b876b5e4-aca4-4caa-b00f-5c00249f8638)

```
  "error": null,
  "metadata": {
    "total": 1,
    "limit": 1000,
    "offset": 0
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
  "description": "10 licenses",
  "closeDate": "2018-05-22",
  "date": "2018-05-22",
  "notes": "",
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Gustav Petterson",
    "role": null,
    "email": "apidocs@upsales.com"
  },
  "client": {
    "name": "Pied piper",
    "id": 2,
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Gustav Petterson",
        "role": null,
        "email": "apidocs@upsales.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  "contact": null,
  "project": null,
  "regDate": "2018-05-22T11:08:26.000Z",
  "stage": {
    "name": "Won - Order",
    "id": 12
  },
  "probability": 100,
  "modDate": "2018-05-22T11:13:59.000Z",
  "clientConnection": null,
  "currencyRate": 1,
  "currency": "SEK",
  "locked": 0,
  "custom": [
    {
      "value": "2018-05-23",
      "valueDate": "2018-05-23",
      "orgNumber": 20180523,
      "fieldId": 1
    }
  ],
  "orderRow": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": 10000,
      "discount": 0,
      "custom": [],
      "productId": 1,
      "sortId": 1,
      "listPrice": 10000,
      "product": {
        "name": "Example product",
        "id": 1,
        "category": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "value": 10000,
  "weightedValue": 10000,
  "valueInMasterCurrency": 10000,
  "weightedValueInMasterCurrency": 10000,
  "agreement": null,
  "userRemovable": true,
  "userEditable": true
}
  ]
}
```

So, I've tried to parse this into my sheets but struggled for quite some time now. What I wanted to do is get all order details into a sheet, but several levels of nested parts were constantly bugging me.

In "Data" everything goes well until it runs till the first nested item "users" that is Dictionary, or "Clients" that is Collection. I tried to run the next loop to fetch nested items but I created an even bigger mess.

```
Sub GetOrders()

Dim sGetResult As String

Dim d_lr As Double

Dim httpObject As Object
Dim dict_json As Object

Dim objData
Dim objOrder

d_lr = LastRow(ActiveSheet)

Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        
    sURL = "https://integration.upsales.com/api/v2/orders?token=" & wAdmin.Range("C4") & "&probability=100"
        
    sRequest = sURL
    httpObject.Open "GET", sRequest, False

    httpObject.setRequestHeader "Accept: ", "application/json"
    httpObject.Send
    sGetResult = httpObject.responseText

    Set dict_json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sGetResult)
    Set objData = dict_json("data")

    For Each objOrder In objData
        For i = 0 To objOrder.Count - 1
            Debug.Print objOrder.Items()(i)
        Next I
    Next objOrder

End Sub
```

Comment: User @omegastripes has written some really nice utilities to handles this sort of situ. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53774575/6241235) or some of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=json++user%3A2165759+is%3Aanswer)

Comment: It's difficult to answer this without knowing how you expect this to look in your worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test the object type and recurse accordingly.

```vb
    Set dict_json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sGetResult)
    Set objdata = dict_json("data")(1)
    
    Dim k, v, u, p
    For Each k In objdata
    
       If VarType(objdata(k)) = 9 Then ' object
          
            If k = "user" Then
                For Each u In objdata(k)
                    Debug.Print "user", u, objdata(k)(u)
                Next
            End If
          
            If k = "client" Then
                For Each u In objdata(k)
                    If u = "users" Then
                        ' for each loop for users
                        For i = 1 To objdata(k)(u).Count
                            For Each p In objdata(k)(u)(i)
                                Debug.Print "users", i, p, objdata(k)(u)(i)(p)
                            Next
                        Next
                    Else
                        Debug.Print "client", u, objdata(k)(u)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
          
       Else
           Debug.Print k, objdata(k)
       End If
       
    Next
```

Comment: Fantastic. With little adjustment exactly what I needed! In actual data set there is few more nested levels but now I know what to do! Thank you!

Comment: I had to ask one small thing again... objData("client")("user") is Collection. It should have 4 items but counts get only 1 and for each loop breaks.`for each v in objData("client")("users")`. v is Empty...

Comment: @MrK `objData("client")("user")` is a collection of objects. It has 1 object with 4 properties, I have updated my answer.