# What is the data format?

Tags: excel, xml, database, formatting

I have a data format that looks like this:

[image]

Do you know what is the best way to open it in excel so it reads properly un columns?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like Newline Delimited JSON also known as JSON Lines.  See e.g. http://ndjson.org/, https://jsonlines.org/

Comment: Json represents objects, so you'd need to first parse it, and then flatten it because the object contains other objects.

Comment: Thank you @MathieuGuindon. I have not done this before, is there a way to parse JSON directly to excel?

Comment: @SurenGrigoryan - Seems like you can do it with [tag:vba], see [Parsing JSON in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6627652/3744182) or [Parsing JSON data into Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53771291).  But to give a proper answer we would need to see a well-formed, complete JSON sample as **text** (not as a screen shot).

Comment: thank you @dbc i have posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74416420/json-parsing-from-txt-file-to-excel