# JSON parsing from txt file to Excel

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have a data that was identified as having JSON format. The data is in a *.txt file and the following is a snapshot from the text:

```
{"company_number":"09145694","data":{"address":{"address_line_1":"St. Andrews Road","country":"England","locality":"Henley-On-Thames","postal_code":"RG9 1HP","premises":"2"},"ceased_on":"2018-05-14","country_of_residence":"England","date_of_birth":{"month":2,"year":1977},"etag":"3b8caf795c03af63921e381f7bb8300a51ebb73d","kind":"individual-person-with-significant-control","links":{"self":"/company/09145694/persons-with-significant-control/individual/bIhuKnMFctSnjrDjUG8n3NgOrlU"},"name":"Mrs Nga Thanh Wildman","name_elements":{"forename":"Nga","middle_name":"Thanh","surname":"Wildman","title":"Mrs"},"nationality":"Vietnamese","natures_of_control":["ownership-of-shares-50-to-75-percent"],"notified_on":"2016-04-06"}}
    {"company_number":"08581893","data":{"address":{"address_line_1":"High Street","address_line_2":"Wendover","country":"England","locality":"Aylesbury","postal_code":"HP22 6EA","premises":"14a","region":"Buckinghamshire"},"ceased_on":"2016-07-01","country_of_residence":"England","date_of_birth":{"month":9,"year":1947},"etag":"45f9c9e5494b574eb52abc3990a49bd96fe09df3","kind":"individual-person-with-significant-control","links":{"self":"/company/08581893/persons-with-significant-control/individual/RgR9Zhc7yGhV0SBys8_WJ6H9O1o"},"name":"Mr Stephen Robert Charles Davies","name_elements":{"forename":"Stephen","middle_name":"Robert Charles","surname":"Davies","title":"Mr"},"nationality":"British","natures_of_control":["ownership-of-shares-25-to-50-percent","ownership-of-shares-25-to-50-percent-as-firm"],"notified_on":"2016-06-30"}}
{"company_number":"08581893","data":{"address":{"address_line_1":"High Street","address_line_2":"Wendover","country":"England","locality":"Aylesbury","postal_code":"HP22 6EA","premises":"14a","region":"Buckinghamshire"},"ceased_on":"2016-07-01","country_of_residence":"England","date_of_birth":{"month":6,"year":1965},"etag":"d55168c49f85ab1ef38a12ed76238d68f79f5a01","kind":"individual-person-with-significant-control","links":{"self":"/company/08581893/persons-with-significant-control/individual/-6HQmkhiomEBXJI2rgHccU67fpM"},"name":"Mr Quentin Colin Maxwell Solt","name_elements":{"forename":"Quentin","middle_name":"Colin Maxwell","surname":"Solt","title":"Mr"},"nationality":"British","natures_of_control":["ownership-of-shares-25-to-50-percent","voting-rights-25-to-50-percent"],"notified_on":"2016-06-30"}}
```

How do I transfer this to a normal excel table with appropriate headings please?

The code i Have tried is from the suggestion in the comments and i have added the dictionary to the excel file as described here, suggested by @skin.

github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

I am getting a 424 error on the line

```
Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonText)
```

Here is the code:

```
Sub jsonchik()


Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim JsonTS As TextStream
Dim JsonText As String
Dim Parsed As Dictionary

' Read .json file
Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("psc-snapshot-2022-11-12_1of22.txt", ForReading)
JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
JsonTS.Close

' Parse json to Dictionary
' "values" is parsed as Collection
' each item in "values" is parsed as Dictionary
Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonText)

' Prepare and write values to sheet
Dim Values As Variant
ReDim Values(Parsed("values").Count, 3)

Dim Value As Dictionary
Dim i As Long

i = 0
For Each Value In Parsed("values")
  Values(i, 0) = Value("a")
  Values(i, 1) = Value("b")
  Values(i, 2) = Value("c")
  i = i + 1
Next Value

Sheets("example").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Parsed("values").Count, 3)) = Values


End Sub
```

Many thanks,

Suren

Comment: You use a library like this … https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: thank you @Skin. I have tried using the link but I am getting an error on Run time "424" error on line: "Set Parsed = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonText)".

Comment: @SurenGrigoryan Did you add the JsonConverter module to your project?

Comment: Always helps to show the code you tried.

Comment: @TimWilliams, - thank you for your comment, i have updated the question with the code that i have tried.

Comment: I'm not finding that parsing library to work very well. You probably should seek other tools here.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, using Microsfot Query, which has a JSON parser.

First, my data had some problems, so i had to validate it here: [https://jsonlint.com/][1]

second, I use MS Excel/Get & Transform Data/from Text/CSV to import my data.

In Importing Wisard, I clicked Transform Data, instead of Load to:

Under Transform Menu/Text Column/Parse/Json.

Works like a charm!

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You get this because you haven't loaded the code for `JsonConverter`.

1. Download the zip file with the code

[image]

2. Unzip the content
3. Right-click on your project and Import the file named JsonConverter.bas

[image]

Now, `JsonConverter` will refer to the module you just imported and `ParseJson` to the method in that module.

**Remark:**
I'm suspecting that you don't have [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement) set at the top of your module. If you had, you would get a "Variable Undefined Error" with `ParseJson` highlighted. That would certainly be more informative in terms error messaging. And that's just one of the good reasons to use Option Explicit!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json library in Python to convert the JSON file to a CSV file, example:

```
import json
import csv

# Open the JSON file
with open('yourfile.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:

    json_data = []
    # Read the file line by line
    for line in json_file:
        json_data.append(json.loads(line))
        
    # Open a CSV file for writing
    with open('yourfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        fieldnames = ['company_number', 'address_line_1', 'country', 'locality', 'postal_code', 'premises', 'ceased_on', 'country_of_residence', 'date_of_birth', 'name', 'nationality', 'natures_of_control', 'notified_on']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        # Write each JSON object as a row in the CSV file
        for json_object in json_data:
            company_number = json_object['company_number']
            address = json_object['data']['address']
            address_line_1 = address['address_line_1']
            country = address['country']
            locality = address['locality']
            postal_code = address['postal_code']
            premises = address['premises']
            ceased_on = json_object['data']['ceased_on']
            country_of_residence = json_object['data']['country_of_residence']
            date_of_birth = json_object['data']['date_of_birth']
            name = json_object['data']['name']
            nationality = json_object['data']['nationality']
            natures_of_control = json_object['data']['natures_of_control']
            notified_on = json_object['data']['notified_on']

            writer.writerow({'company_number': company_number, 'address_line_1': address_line_1, 'country': country, 'locality': locality, 'postal_code': postal_code, 'premises': premises, 'ceased_on': ceased_on, 'country_of_residence': country_of_residence, 'date_of_birth': date_of_birth, 'name': name, 'nationality': nationality, 'natures_of_control': natures_of_control, 'notified_on': notified_on})
```

Comment: This question is about VBA not python unfortunately.